# How to make outlook report meeting invites to a different e-mail address?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

A typical situation for those affiliated with several corporations is having separate e-mail addresses and laptops within each corporation. Sometimes security policies do not allow mobile access to at least one of the mailboxes. And there is often a tendency to ignore one mailbox while focusing on another. However, unfortunately, meeting invites sometimes arrive in the other mailbox in parallel. If not checked frequently, some invites get ignored with time.

The question is about introducing the following behaviour. When Outlook receives an e-mail which is a meeting invite, send an e-mail that there is a meeting invite (not forwarding; company security is unhappy about forwarding) to another mailbox.

Is there any web plugin or configuration doing such a routine? The interest is primarily in such behaviour through the web-based Outlook. For a local outlook, there is, of course, an opportunity to write scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mail flow rule in Outlook to accomplish your requirement. It is safer and more convenient rather than third-party scripts.

Here are the detailed steps about how to configure mail flow rule:
1.Navigate to **File**->**Manage Rules and Alerts**
2.Select **Apply Rule on messages |receive** below **Start from a blank rule**
3.In rule wizard select **which is a meeting invitation or update** ,then click **next**
4.Slect **forward it to people or public group**,you can select the people or public group you want to forward to.
5.Click **finish**.

Comment: Forwarding unavailable. More precisely, forwarding outside organization is blocked on the webmail level.

Comment: About external email forwarding, have you ever considered using Microsoft 365? The Microsoft 365 can use outbound spam filter policies to control forwarding. For more information ,please info this Microsoft Document:[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/outbound-spam-policies-external-email-forwarding?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: That sounds like advice for Microsoft 365 administrators. I am looking for something that works for Microsoft 365 users.

Comment: Sorry ,for Microsoft 365 users ,it may face insufficient permissions.